# Mutilselect Select Box over Ajax (jQuery/Laravel 4)

Tags: jquery, ajax, serialization, laravel-4

I have a multiselect select box of languages.
In a normal post I found that `Input::get('languages)` returns an array of values and that is perfectly behaving.

On another place I am posting whole form over jQuery post/ajax. I have tried both `jQuery('form').serialize()` and jQuery('form').serializeArray()`.

In case of `serialize` the result is `... languages=X&languages=Y ...`
And in case of `serializeArray` the result is `[... {languages: X}, {language: Y} ...]`

But I am getting only a single value via `Input::get('languages')` however it is working perfectly in normal post method.

What am I doing wrong here?
How to deal with multiselect select box via ajax way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you name the select as an array using the `[]` notation:

```
<select name="languages[]" multiple>
```

For more info check the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays) on the subject.